# Starting a container only after the previous container is Running

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Lets say I have 3 containers X,Y and Z. I want container Y to start only after container X is running, and container Z to start only after Y is running.

How do I do this?

Comment: As you seem to be new to StackOverflow - a good advice before asking anything is to have a look into the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution which worked for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview) file with the [`depends_on`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#dependson) option to control container start order

Here is how the `docker-compose.yml` for your example would look like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  X:
    image: X_image

  Y:
    image: Y_image
    depends_on: X

  Z:
    image: Z_image
    depends_on: Y
```

> **Note**: `depends_on` will not wait for X to be “ready” before starting Y - only until it's running. If you need to wait for a service to be ready, see [Controlling startup order](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order) for more on this problem and strategies for solving it.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider to redesign your application parts if they have such heavy dependencies, then they should maybe not be split to different containers or you should use some decoupeling to avoid

What you could do is to:

1. Have one ore more [init containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/abstractions/init-containers/#init-containers-in-use)
2. Have a [entrypoint script](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) within each of the containers which blocks until the dependency is fulfilled
3. Implement something outside the cluster which controls which pods are started.
4. Write a [custom controller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=66NzGKJpyyg)

Comment: Good advice. An entrypoint script with a sleep is a workable, if blunt, solution. Ideally, the application in container Z would attempt to reconnect to container Y at a reasonable interval until it finds it. This will make the entire infrastructure more robust.